# 'ALIAS' Terminal Git Bash on Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: here is a screenshot of my terminal in vscode]

I want to remove the **alias** in my git bash terminal in this visual studio code, please help me how to **remove it**. Or how to return to the default git bash without the **alias** line above. I have reinstalled the git application but there is no change.

Comment: find the location of the home directory of your bash login, show the `.` files and one `.bash*` file contains the command to show the `alias` command on `login`

Comment: `unalias youralias`